# Powershell and schtask with task that has a space

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am using the `schtask` command with PowerShell. The problem that occurs is, when the program/script argument contains `C:\Program Files\`, it thinks the path is just `C:\Program` and the rest of the path is an argument. I have tried to escape it by using `"` pre- and post- field, but it did n'tmake a difference. How can I accomplish this? I cannot hard-code the path because it can be changed when the user installs it.

I was creating this in Windows 7 x64. It creates the task OK and the script returns. However, when I view it in the Task Scheduler, properties of the task, then actions, and hit `edit`, It shows the program as C:\Program and then the rest as the argument.

[image]

Script:

```
$folder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$app = "\Demon.DatabasePurge.exe"
$exe = $app.Insert(0, $folder)
schtasks /create /tn "Demon Purge Job" /sc daily /st 00:00:00 /tr $exe
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$folder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$app = "\Demon.DatabasePurge.exe`""
$exe = $app.Insert(0, $folder)
$exe2 = $exe.Insert(0, "`"")
schtasks /create /tn "Demon Purge Job" /sc daily /st 00:00:00 /tr $exe2
```

Comment: I tried it out using the notepad++ exe under C:\Program Files and your original code worked fine. It created a scheduled task for me.

Comment: Your original code is working for me too with C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToy.exe. On which OS are you working ?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specifically clear. I am able to create the task; however, it will not run. I was using Win7. So I create the task and if you browse the task, right click properties, actions, edit. My task would show the program as C:\Program and then the rest of the path as the argument. I'll update the description.

Answer (score 23):

I was having problems with this as well.. anyone else with this issue the answer is to include single quotes

```
/TR "'C:\Program Files (x86)\etc\test.exe'"
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on Windows Server 2008 R2. While [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823093) indicates you should be able to surround the command with \" I never got that to work, but single quotes work. Moreover, arguments with spaces can also be surrounded in single quotes:

```
schtasks /create /f /tn "Test" /tr "'c:\program files\test.bat' arg1 'arg 2 with spaces' arg3" /sc Daily /st 00:00
```

or when building up a string to execute (and using your $folder variable):

```
$createTask = "schtasks /create /f /tn `"Demon Purge Job`" /tr `"'$folder\Demon.DatabasePurge.exe' arg1 'arg 2 with spaces' arg3`"" /sc daily /st 00:00
Invoke-Expression $createTask
```

The first example produces the following task action screen:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To work around this problem, enclose the path portion of the task (not including arguments or switches) between backslash `\` and quotation marks `"` character combinations, for example `\"`. Enclose the complete path of the task (including arguments or switches) between quotation marks as usual when you create a path or command that contains spaces.

Code:

```
schtasks /create /f /tn "Test" /tr "'c:\program files\test.bat' arg1 'arg 2 with spaces' arg3" /sc Daily /st 00:00
```

Replace:

```
schtasks /create /f /tn "Test" /tr "\"c:\program files\test.bat\" arg1 'arg 2 with spaces' arg3" /sc Daily /st 00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The command line help already provides the solution:

```
schtasks /create /?
```

> ```
> ==> Spaces in file paths can be used by using two sets of quotes, one
>     set for CMD.EXE and one for SchTasks.exe.  The outer quotes for CMD
>     need to be double quotes; the inner quotes can be single quotes or
>     escaped double quotes:
>     SCHTASKS /Create
>        /tr "'c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplorer.exe'
>        \"c:\log data\today.xml\"" ...
> ```