# Inno Setup, spaces and double quote in [Run]

Tags: inno-setup, quotes, spaces

I'm trying to schedule a task on Windows, and unfortunately, it doesn't work!
The task is created but not correctly.

When I look into task's parameters, it says:

```
PROGRAM: C:\Program
ARGUMENTS: Files(x86)\AppName\executable.exe
```

This is how I proceed:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; Parameters: "/create /tn TaskName /sc MINUTE /mo 10 /tr ""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}""";
```

And I don't know why it doesn't work, doubles quotes should fix the "spaces problem"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is known and is described in [`this knowledge base article`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823093/en-us). You will need to enclose the file name between combination of backslash and quotation marks. That article describes:

> **Cause:**
>
> This problem occurs if the path of the scheduled task contains a
>   space. For example, this problem occurs if you create a schedule for
>   the following task by using Schtasks.exe:
>
> ```
>  "c:\foldername containing spaces\task.bat"
> ```
>
> **Workaround:**
>
> To work around this problem, enclose the path portion of the task (not
>   including arguments or switches) between backslash (\) and quotation
>   marks (") character combinations, for example \". Enclose the complete
>   path of the task (including arguments or switches) between quotation
>   marks as usual when you create a path or command that contains spaces.
>
> For example, the following example task does not run when you schedule
>   it:
>
> ```
>  schtasks /create /tn "my task" /tr "c:\foldername containing spaces\script.bat arguments" /sc once /sd 07/29/2003 /st 10:01
> ```
>
> However, when you enclose the path of the task between the backslash
>   and quotation marks character combinations as in the following
>   example, the scheduled task runs successfully:
>
> ```
>  schtasks /create /tn "my task" /tr "\"c:\foldername name containing spaces\script.bat\" arguments" /sc once /sd 07/29/2003 /st 10:01
> ```

So in your case it could be:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; Parameters: "/create /tn TaskName /sc MINUTE /mo 10 /tr ""\""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}\""";
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank's a lot. What a fast answer :o

Comment: This workaround is also applicable to other, similar concepts as well. Relevant example: Filename: `powershell.exe; Parameters: "-Command some-command -Description ""\""some description with spaces in it\"""` Too bad it totally destroys syntax highlighting around it..

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. However I think you're still missing some quotes in your final code block: `""\""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}\"""` has `""`for the leading quote in the final command, `\""` for the escaped quote in the path, followed by `\""` for the closing escaped quote and `"` for the closing quote of the parameters string. If I'm not mistaken, this misses another `""` for the closing quote of the string in the final command. so it should look like this: `""\""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}\"""""`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but as mentioned [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079439/158371), you could try to simply add single quotes around your /TR parameter, which would result in

```
Parameters: "/create /tn TaskName /sc MINUTE /mo 10 /tr '"{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"'";
```

That might be a bit easier than juggling backslashes.