# Inno Setup, spaces in parameters in [Run]

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create a setup with Inno Setup.

In the run section, I want to launch a bat with two parameters but in the first parameters, there is a path file and a space is potentially inside. How to avoid the problem?

I found this topic in vain...
[Inno Setup, spaces and double quote in [Run]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611855/inno-setup-spaces-and-double-quote-in-run)

Thanks for your help.

```
[Run]
Filename: {code:GetDirSQL|0}\installSQL\createBase\launchCreateParam.bat;
    Parameters:  {code:GetDirSQL|0}\installSQL\createBase {code:GetDossier|0}; 
    Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,LumisTraiteur}; 
    StatusMsg: Création de la base de données...; Check: instalDossier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Parameters in Sections](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params):

```
Parameters: """{code:GetDirSQL|0}\installSQL\createBase"" ""{code:GetDossier|0}"""
```

---

It may get more complicated, when the application, you are running, treats the quotes and spaces specially:

- [How to handle path with spaces in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47281316/850848)
- [Inno Setup, spaces and double quote in [Run]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23611855/850848)